# Where can I find shapefiles of US counties and districts?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, data-sources, voting-districts

I am interested in creating some nice plots of election results from this and previous election cycles. I am wondering if there is a publicly available database or website that contains shapefiles of US counties and house districts?

Furthermore if it contains historical district datasets that would be a big plus as well.

Comment: Probably will get a faster/better answer on opendata.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find shapefiles from the US census:

https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/cartographic-boundary.html

Shapefiles and kml files are both available for congressional district, counties and other categories used by the census.

Some historical data is available from https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html But this only goes back to the 1990s.